# How to update list view without refreshing in Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, listview

How can it update a list view elements without doing pull-to-refresh
If I'm adding an element in a dialog window or from an Api, how to add/update the list view elements automatically.

Should I use StreamBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use state management pub like `Getx`, or something with `adlistener`.

Comment: @SanjayChakrapani please mark complete my answer. and upvote me

Comment: I'm using Getx for state management, wrapped the listview-builder inside .obx widget,

Comment: is ma answer fullfil your question?

Comment: ya it was, I will upvote you as soon as I get enough to do

Comment: Please check there is an option to mark as complete beside my answer, so people can get the answer is workable. and you will get point also

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use stream builder and you can also use setstate

```
setState(() { });
```

Comment: Thank you for the replay, I tried setSate(), but not helping. If I add a button to do setSate() it is working.

Answer (score 0):

StreamBuilder Widget builds itself based on the latest snapshot of interaction with a Stream. Thus the state of the app changes whenever new elements are added in the list as long as the connection status is active.

You can also use the combination of ListView Builder and setState method, though the state of the app needs to change whenever a new element is added. Earlier StreamBuilder widget was updating the state of the app. Various methods like adding a button to the screen, which can help the user manually change the state; can be used depending on the use case.

You can read more about it from the official docs: [setState method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)
[StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not exactly about updating listView, but updating a widget(PiChart). As listview is also a widget, the implementation will be the same to update without refreshing.

In this method, I am using streamBuilder to update the widget. so need not refresh the app to update the data.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69800324/13577765